# Retrieve values from link Angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript

My link is: http://localhost:4200/EditQuestionnaire;id=1;name=Random%20Questionnaire

And in ngOnInit() I am executing this code but cannot get the values

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.questionnaireName = params['name'];
    this.questionnaireID = params['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActivatedRoute` as below

```
constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute){
    this.activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.questionnaireName = params['name'];
      this.questionnaireID = params['id'];
    });
}
```

And your url should correct as `http://localhost:4200/EditQuestionnaire?id=1&name=Random%20Questionnaire`

Answer (score 0):

```
public id:string;

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){
    this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id;
}
```